# use WHERE in mysql join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to use WHERE in mysql join

```
SELECT user.name , course.name
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `course` on user.course = course.id;
```

i want to add `WHERE name='Alice'` in `user.name`

i tried to do it via :

```
SELECT user.name WHERE name='Alice' , course.name
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `course` on user.course = course.id;
```

or
    SELECT user.name  , course.name
    FROM `user` WHERE user.name='Alice'
    LEFT JOIN `course` on user.course = course.id;

but it seam they are wrong

how can i use `WHERE` in Mysql join ( inner join , left join ,... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, the correct syntax is

```
SELECT
FROM
JOIN
ON
WHERE
```

So in your case it will be

```
SELECT a.name, b.name as bname
FROM `user` a
LEFT JOIN `course` b 
ON a.course = b.id
WHERE a.name='Alice'
```

Note that i used an alias since two columns have the same name

Answer (score 1):

Almost right. This should work fine:

```
SELECT u.name, c.name
FROM `user` u
LEFT JOIN `course` c on u.course = c.id WHERE u.name='Alice';
```

I know, it's weird to think about, but that's actually how you do it.

And I changed to `u` and `c` because it's neater to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Im not use but may try this.

```
SELECT user.name AS user_name, course.name AS course_name
FROM user
LEFT JOIN course
ON user.id = course.id
WHERE user.name = 'Alice';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create alias for your table or sub-query, then you can simply approach to data in the table.

There is old article but nothing changed in SQL. It will be usefull for you. 
Third example is solution for your problem.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/additional-criteria-in-the-join-clause